# Fundamentals In creating a better Text with java

Tags: python

There are some versions of the java compiler where the sort() method of the Vector class is not yet implemented. If you are not using JDK 1.8 version or higher, use the Collections class instead to sort your Vector data. Sample use below

There are some versions of the java compiler where the sort() method of the Vector class is not yet implemented. If you are not using JDK 1.8 version or higher, use the Collections class instead to sort your Vector data. Sample use below

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Vector;

public class Main {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        try {
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("c://student.txt"));
            char g;
            int yl, I;
            String ln, fn, id, cors, con;
            Student v[] = new Student[4];
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
            boolean en = true;
            boolean ent = true;

            for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
                id = br.readLine();
                ln = br.readLine();
                fn = br.readLine();
                g = br.readLine().charAt(0);
                cors = br.readLine();
                yl = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());

                v[i] = new Student(ln, fn, id, cors, g, yl);
            }

            while (en == true) {
                System.out.println("--------------------------------------");
                System.out.println("--------------------------------------");
                System.out.println("1. Name");
                System.out.println("2. Course then Name");
                System.out.println("3. Year Level then Name");
                System.out.println("4. Course then Year Level and the Name");
                System.out.println("5. Exit");
                System.out.println("--------------------------------------");
                System.out.println("--------------------------------------");
                System.out.println("Choose Menu: ");
                int choice = sc.nextInt();
                switch (choice) {
                    case 1:
                        Arrays.sort(v);
                        display_array(v);
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        Arrays.sort(v);
                        display_array(v);
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        Arrays.sort(v);
                        display_array(v);
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        Arrays.sort(v);
                        display_array(v);
                        break;
                    case 5:
                        en = false;
                        System.out.println("\n\n \nTHANK YOU FOR USING THE PROGRAM!!");
                        break;
                }
                if (en != false) {
                    System.out.println("Press [Enter key] to continue");
                    try {
                        System.in.read();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.err.println("File not found");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("Unable to read the file.");
        }
    }
    public static void display_array(Student arr_v[]) throws IOException {
        System.out.println("--------------------------------------");
        for (int i = 0; i < arr_v.length; i++) {
            arr_v[i].display();
        }
        System.out.println("--------------------------------------");
    }
}

public class Student implements Comparable {
    private String lastname, firstname, studentid, course;
    private char gender;
    private int yearlevel;

    public Student(String ln, String fn, String id, String cors, char g, int yl) {
        lastname = ln;
        firstname = fn;
        studentid = id;
        course = cors;
        gender = g;
        yearlevel = yl;
    }

    public int compareTo(Object anotherObject) {
        Student anotherStudent = (Student) anotherObject;
        int compareResult =
            this.course.compareTo(anotherStudent.lastname);
        if (compare)
            return 0;
    }
    public void display() {
        System.out.printf("ID: %-8s  Name: %-20s  Sex: %c  Course: %-8s  Year: %d\n", studentid, (lastname + ", " + firstname), gender, course, yearlevel);
    }

    public void setGender(char gender) {
        this.gender = gender;
    }

    public char getGender() {
        return gender;
    }

    public void setLastname(String lastname) {
        this.lastname = lastname;
    }

    public String getLastname() {
        return lastname;
    }

    public void setFirstname(String firstname) {
        this.firstname = firstname;
    }

    public String getFirstname() {
        return firstname;
    }

    public void setStudentId(String studentid) {
        this.studentid = studentid;
    }

    public String getStudentId() {
        return studentid;
    }

    public void setCourse(String course) {
        this.course = course;
    }

    public String getCourse() {
        return course;
    }

    public void setYearLevel(int yearlevel) {
        this.yearlevel = yearlevel;
    }

    public int getYearLevel() {
        return yearlevel;
    }
}
```

Comment: Ans what is your question? This is basically just a code dump. You may want to read [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So there were actual 2 bugs in your code:

1. In reading from test.

```
                id = br.readLine();
                ln = br.readLine();
                fn = br.readLine();
                g = br.readLine().charAt(0);
                cors = br.readLine();
                yl = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
```

2. `Comparable`

1.When you readLine it takes the entire line, even the `spaces` so when you write `br.readLine()` it will read this `20192215 Ang Bryan m BSCS 4` whole line in once.
and what you have done is you have called it `6 times` and there ain't enough `lines` in there.
what you can do is. Read a line and the `split` it in `array` when you encounter `space` and then just use `index` to get `20192215 Ang Bryan m BSCS 4` below is how you should do it.

```
                int yl;
                String ln, fn, id, cors, con,g;
               for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
                    String line = br.readLine();
                    String studentInfo[] = line.split(" ");
                    id = studentInfo[0];
                    ln = studentInfo[1];
                    fn = studentInfo[2];
                    g  = studentInfo[3];
                    cors = studentInfo[4];
                    yl = Integer.parseInt(studentInfo[5]);

                    v[i] = new Student(ln, fn, id, cors, g, yl);
                }
```

here `split(" ")` will split the string into String of `array` and `split on  *space*`.

2. When you use `Comparable` that means you want your `object` to sort in only `one way` that can be `name` or `year` or anything else. 
   But only in one way either `name` or `year` or something else. It will not change its behavior.
   Whereas if you use `Comparator` it allows you to sort the object in multiple ways. It overcomes the issue of  `Comparable`.

This is how you use a`Comparator`

```
class sortName implements Comparator<Student>{

    @Override
    public int compare(Student o1, Student o2) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String fname1 = o1.getFirstname();
        String fname2 = o2.getFirstname();
        return fname1.compareTo(fname2);
    }
}
```

Your option as where you wanted to sort according to the option selected.
option 1:

```
class sortName implements Comparator<Student>{

    @Override
    public int compare(Student o1, Student o2) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String fname1 = o1.getFirstname();
        String fname2 = o2.getFirstname();
        return fname1.compareTo(fname2);
    }
}
```

Option 2:

```
class sortCourse_name implements Comparator<Student>{

    @Override
    public int compare(Student o1, Student o2) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String firstCourse = o1.getCourse();
        String secondCourse = o2.getCourse();
        String fname1 = o1.getFirstname();
        String sname2 = o2.getFirstname();
        if(firstCourse.compareTo(secondCourse) == 0) {
            return fname1.compareTo(sname2);
        }else {
            return firstCourse.compareTo(secondCourse);
        }
    }
}
```

Option 3:

```
class sort_Year_Name implements Comparator<Student>{

    @Override
    public int compare(Student o1, Student o2) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        int firstYear = o1.getYearLevel();
        int secondYear = o2.getYearLevel();
        String fname = o1.getFirstname();
        String sname = o2.getFirstname();
        if(firstYear - secondYear == 0) {
            return fname.compareTo(sname);
        }else {
            return firstYear - secondYear;
        }
    }
}
```

Option 4:

```
class sort_Course_Year_Name implements Comparator<Student>{

    @Override
    public int compare(Student o1, Student o2) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String fcourse = o1.getCourse();
        String scourse = o2.getCourse();
        
        int firstYear = o1.getYearLevel();
        int secondYear = o2.getYearLevel();
        
        String fname = o1.getFirstname();
        String sname = o2.getFirstname();
        
        if(fcourse.compareTo(scourse) == 0 ) {
            if(firstYear - secondYear == 0) {
                return fname.compareTo(sname);
            }else {
                return firstYear-secondYear;
            }
        }else {
            return fcourse.compareTo(scourse);
        }
        
    }
}
```

Changes in  `class Student`

```
class Student {
        private String lastname, firstname, studentid, course, gender;
        private int yearlevel;

        public Student(String ln, String fn, String id, String cors, String g, int yl) {
            lastname = ln;
            firstname = fn;
            studentid = id;
            course = cors;
            gender = g;
            yearlevel = yl;
        }
       public void setGender(String gender) {
            this.gender = gender;
        }

        public String getGender() {
            return gender;
        }
}
```

Whole code:

```
class Main {
     public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
            try {
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("c://student.txt"));
                String g; // changed
                int yl;
                String ln, fn, id, cors, con;
                Student v[] = new Student[4];
                Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
                boolean en = true;
                boolean ent = true;

                // changed
                for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
                    String line = br.readLine();
                    String studentInfo[] = line.split(" ");
                    id = studentInfo[0];
                    ln = studentInfo[1];
                    fn = studentInfo[2];
                    g  = studentInfo[3];
                    cors = studentInfo[4];
                    yl = Integer.parseInt(studentInfo[5]);

                    v[i] = new Student(ln, fn, id, cors, g, yl);
                }

                while (en == true) {
                    System.out.println("--------------------------------------");
                    System.out.println("--------------------------------------");
                    System.out.println("1. Name");
                    System.out.println("2. Course then Name");
                    System.out.println("3. Year Level then Name");
                    System.out.println("4. Course then Year Level and the Name");
                    System.out.println("5. Exit");
                    System.out.println("--------------------------------------");
                    System.out.println("--------------------------------------");
                    System.out.println("Choose Menu: ");
                    int choice = sc.nextInt();
                    switch (choice) {
                        case 1:
                            // changed
                            Arrays.sort(v,new sortName());
                            display_array(v);
                            break;
                        case 2:
                            // changed
                            Arrays.sort(v, new sortCourse_name());
                            display_array(v);
                            break;
                        case 3:
                            // changed
                            Arrays.sort(v, new sort_Year_Name());
                            display_array(v);
                            break;
                        case 4:
                            // changed
                            Arrays.sort(v,new sort_Course_Year_Name());
                            display_array(v);
                            break;
                        case 5:
                            en = false;
                            System.out.println("\n\n \nTHANK YOU FOR USING THE PROGRAM!!");
                            break;
                    }
                    if (en != false) {
                        System.out.println("Press [Enter key] to continue");
                        try {
                            System.in.read();
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                System.err.println("File not found");
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.err.println("Unable to read the file.");
            }
        }
        public static void display_array(Student arr_v[]) throws IOException {
            System.out.println("--------------------------------------");
            for (int i = 0; i < arr_v.length; i++) {
                arr_v[i].display();
            }
            System.out.println("--------------------------------------");
        }
    }

    class Student {
        private String lastname, firstname, studentid, course, gender;
        private int yearlevel;
        //changed
        public Student(String ln, String fn, String id, String cors, String g, int yl) {
            lastname = ln;
            firstname = fn;
            studentid = id;
            course = cors;
            gender = g;
            yearlevel = yl;
        }

        public void display() {
            System.out.printf("ID: %-8s  Name: %-20s  Sex: %s  Course: %-8s  Year: %d\n", studentid, (lastname + ", " + firstname), gender, course, yearlevel);
        }
        // changed
        public void setGender(String gender) {
            this.gender = gender;
        }
        // changed
        public String getGender() {
            return gender;
        }

        public void setLastname(String lastname) {
            this.lastname = lastname;
        }

        public String getLastname() {
            return lastname;
        }

        public void setFirstname(String firstname) {
            this.firstname = firstname;
        }

        public String getFirstname() {
            return firstname;
        }

        public void setStudentId(String studentid) {
            this.studentid = studentid;
        }

        public String getStudentId() {
            return studentid;
        }

        public void setCourse(String course) {
            this.course = course;
        }

        public String getCourse() {
            return course;
        }

        public void setYearLevel(int yearlevel) {
            this.yearlevel = yearlevel;
        }

        public int getYearLevel() {
            return yearlevel;
        }
    }
// added    
class sortName implements Comparator<Student>{

    @Override
    public int compare(Student o1, Student o2) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String fname1 = o1.getFirstname();
        String fname2 = o2.getFirstname();
        return fname1.compareTo(fname2);
    }
}
//added
class sortCourse_name implements Comparator<Student>{

    @Override
    public int compare(Student o1, Student o2) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String firstCourse = o1.getCourse();
        String secondCourse = o2.getCourse();
        String fname1 = o1.getFirstname();
        String sname2 = o2.getFirstname();
        if(firstCourse.compareTo(secondCourse) == 0) {
            return fname1.compareTo(sname2);
        }else {
            return firstCourse.compareTo(secondCourse);
        }
    }
}
//added
class sort_Year_Name implements Comparator<Student>{

    @Override
    public int compare(Student o1, Student o2) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        int firstYear = o1.getYearLevel();
        int secondYear = o2.getYearLevel();
        String fname = o1.getFirstname();
        String sname = o2.getFirstname();
        if(firstYear - secondYear == 0) {
            return fname.compareTo(sname);
        }else {
            return firstYear - secondYear;
        }
    }
}
//added
class sort_Course_Year_Name implements Comparator<Student>{

    @Override
    public int compare(Student o1, Student o2) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String fcourse = o1.getCourse();
        String scourse = o2.getCourse();
        
        int firstYear = o1.getYearLevel();
        int secondYear = o2.getYearLevel();
        
        String fname = o1.getFirstname();
        String sname = o2.getFirstname();
        
        if(fcourse.compareTo(scourse) == 0 ) {
            if(firstYear - secondYear == 0) {
                return fname.compareTo(sname);
            }else {
                return firstYear-secondYear;
            }
        }else {
            return fcourse.compareTo(scourse);
        }
        
    }
}
```

Comment: Sir @Swapnil Thank you very much I made it this far I was close to giving up because I got confused by using switch and array assort. I couldn't find any references for  problems like these.

Comment: It's all part of learning, You were actually trying to solve a tricky problem on your own, and you made a try for it. which just made you realize what not to do and what to do.  Keep learning and keep discovering more in java.